# How do I get the number of unique cases used to get the frequency of the other variable using SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have two columns, containing a person's data on repeated measurements and other one with the presence or absence of a characteristic.

Data reads like this (Column wise);

- Patient_Code  : 1  1  2  2  2  3  4  5  5  6  6
- Characteristic: N Y Y Y N N N Y Y N N

I want the number of unique cases used to get the frequencies in other variable. For Ex:
 Y - 5 (from 3 cases/patients)
          N - 6 (from 5 cases/patients).

How do I do this using SPSS. I have several characteristics like this.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to create a unique identifier of Patients within each exposed group. The `SORT CASES` followed by `MATCH FILES` achieves this, the `CTABLES` then tabulates the results.

```
DATA LIST LIST / PatID(f1.0) Exposed(a1).
BEGIN DATA
1 "N"
1 "Y"
2 "Y"
2 "Y"
2 "N"
3 "N"
4 "N"
5 "Y"
5 "Y"
6 "N"
6 "N"
END DATA.

SORT CASES BY Exposed PatID.
MATCH FILES FILE=* /BY Exposed PatID /FIRST=Primary.

CTABLES /VLABELS VARIABLES=Primary DISPLAY=NONE
   /TABLE Exposed[c] by Primary[s][validn 'Count' sum 'Patients']
   /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Exposed ORDER=D
   /TITLES TITL="Table1: Exposure counts; Patients Exposed".
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, this is perfectly fine. It helped a lot. Is there a way to do it using drop down menu as well?

Comment: Yes but you really ought to learn syntax to take forward these methods more easily in future.

Comment: Yes Sir. I understand that Syntax is more helpful for customized tasks like this.

Comment: To get the counts of exposure, a simple aggregation or table would do. It's the unduplicated count of patients which requires the "complication", as I believe @ravi-GS  required and confirmed in his comment.

Comment: Part of the "complication" is requiring CTABLES module which people don't necessarily have (due to high cost). Please see my "AGGREGATE only" solution.

Comment: "High cost" is somewhat subjective. I notice you delete/edited a previous solution you posted only to replicate the results I provided? You may want to read guidance on when it is appropriate to down vote also. To down vote a solution which answers the question at hand (confirmed by the OP) isn't in the spirit of SO community, I would say.

Comment: 1. Apologies - you are right about the downvote - that was a mistake but the system doesn't allow me to undo it (unless, it seems, if it's edited first?)

Comment: 2. I mean the custom tables module involves additional costs, so many don't buy it... That's why I try to find solutions that don't require it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with two AGGREGATE steps:

```
DATA LIST free / PatID(f1) Exposed(a1).
BEGIN DATA
1 N
1 Y
2 Y
2 Y
2 N
3 N
4 N
5 Y
5 Y
6 N
6 N
END DATA.

DATASET DECLARE count1.
DATASET DECLARE count2.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='count1' /BREAK=PatID Exposed /Ncases=N.
dataset activate count1.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='count2'/BREAK=Exposed /Ncases=sum(Ncases)/Nuniques=N.
```

The final results appear in the 'count2' dataset.